# Why does rectX and rectY become NaN?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

rectX and rectY are initialized as 0. Afterwards I'm adding 0 to either 0, or a small amount. I do not understand why it would become NaN all of the sudden. Can someone help me understand?

```js
const context = document.querySelector("#background").getContext("2d");
let rectX = 0;
let rectY = 0;
let movingSpeed = 50;
let secondsPassed = 0;
let oldTimeStamp = 0;
let timePassed = 0;

// Listen to the onLoad event
window.onload = init;

// Trigger init function when the page has loaded
function init() {
  background.width = window.innerWidth;
  background.height = window.innerHeight;

  // Request an animation frame for the first time
  // The gameLoop() function will be called as a callback of this request
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

function gameLoop(timeStamp) {
console.log("timestamp", timeStamp);
  // Calculate how much time has passed
  secondsPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
  oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;

  // Pass the time to the update
  update(secondsPassed);
  draw();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

function update(secondsPassed) {
  // Use time to calculate new position
  rectX += movingSpeed * secondsPassed;
  rectY += movingSpeed * secondsPassed;
  console.log("rect", rectX, rectY);
}

function draw() {
  context.fillStyle = "#ff8080";
  context.fillRect(rectX, rectY, 150, 100);
}
gameLoop();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: default;
}

html {
  background-color: dimgrey;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 93, 93);
}

canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#background {
  background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="background"></canvas>
```

All it does it add number to an initial number of 0. So how does JS suddenly see it as not a number?

Some other text.

Comment: you didnt pass `timeStamp` value while calling `gameLoop` function..?

Comment: change `gameLoop();` to `gameLoop(0);` or `gameLoop(someTimeStamp);`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame
You don't have to, that's what Im seeing.

Comment: @23rfew You absolutely have to, if you call the function yourself, in that example there is no call to the main loop like you have.... just remove that `gameLoop();` from your code and you are good, your init function is taking care of that "initialization"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'mplungjan' mentioned. You can call the loop initially with 0 as a parameter. It fixes the problem quite simply. -> `gameloop()` as `gameloop(0)`.

The actual proper way to do it, however, is to call the loop initially as `window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);`.

Comment: yes, I think the problem ends up being that gameloop is being called twice, once with an undefined and once from the init function, leading to it running twice

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but here's how to fix it.

`requestAnimationFrame` does not get a `timeStamp` as a parameter, so instead use `performance.now()` (more precise than `Date.now().getTime()`) to initialize the `timeStamp`

```js
/** @format */

// Declare as variable
const context = document.querySelector("#background").getContext("2d");
let rectX = 0;
let rectY = 0;
let movingSpeed = 50;
let secondsPassed = 0;
let oldTimeStamp = performance.now();
let timePassed = 0;

// Listen to the onLoad event
window.onload = init;

// Trigger init function when the page has loaded
function init() {
  background.width = window.innerWidth;
  background.height = window.innerHeight;

  // Request an animation frame for the first time
  // The gameLoop() function will be called as a callback of this request
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

function gameLoop() {
  const timeStamp = performance.now()
  // Calculate how much time has passed
  secondsPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
  oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;

  // Pass the time to the update
  update(secondsPassed);
  draw();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

function update(secondsPassed) {
  // Use time to calculate new position
  rectX += movingSpeed * secondsPassed;
  rectY += movingSpeed * secondsPassed;
}

function draw() {
  context.fillStyle = "#ff8080";
  context.fillRect(rectX, rectY, 150, 100);
}
gameLoop();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: default;
}

html {
  background-color: dimgrey;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 93, 93);
}

canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#background {
  background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="background"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why don't they use it here than? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame. As far as I can tell no parameter is given either.

Comment: Interesting. According to the docs your code should work, I agree.

Comment: I completely missed the last line `gameLoop()` - as stated in other comments this is the problem (since it's not a `requestAnimationFrame()` callback). I only saw you starting the loop within `init()`, so it's enough to simply remove the line `gameLoop()` - if the loop doesn't run then, change `window.onload = init;` to `init()`

Answer (score 0):

You call `gameLoop();` without parameters. So  `secondsPassed = (undefined - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;` becomes `undefined` so eventuall you end up with `rectX += movingSpeed * undefined;`

Comment: Timestamp is only undifined once I see now. I do not need to pass it in the loop. So how come it happens one time?